# I updated my iPod 5 gen to iOS 9 and now it has a 6 digit passcode

Tags: icloud, password

I updated my iPod to iOS 9 ( i think, its the current one right now 10/24/15) and my pass code was 5-6-8-9(4 digits) and now after updating it and recovering it through iTunes to prepare to sell it to someone it now has a 6 digit password. What do I do, how do I unlock it now because I really need it to sell it for the money.

Comment: You should have been given the choice, immediately after the update, to change to the new 6-digit or keep the existing 4-digit passcode. Did you allow someone else to do the update for you?

Comment: No, i did it all, at first it was like ' sign in and we can complete set up of the new update" (not those exact words) but i decided to turn it off and leave it at that because someone was buying it, so they would want to log in, and then a few days later i turn it on and it has a pasword

Comment: That wasn't the point at which to switch it off (though doesn't explain why it wants a new code) you should have completed the update the wiped the iPod completely.

Answer (score -4):

Try a factory reset.  Probably has been hacked and someone else has control of the passcode.