# "Enter your passcode" without a passcode

Tags: iphone, ios, password

My iPhone 6 is running iOS 9.1 (13B143), not jailbroken. Installed one app, f.lux, which is sideloaded, everything else is from the App Store.

Occasionally, about once per day, while charging or after unlocking the screen, the phone will present the "Enter your passcode" screen.

*Just to be clear: I have never set a passcode, yes I know the "skip" step during upgrades, I do not have roommates or other people touching my phone, I do not use Touch ID or Apple Pay, and I have never set a passcode.*

The passcode screen includes a full QWERTY keyboard, not the digits one. And entering anything in there will just shake the screen (incorrect passcode). I have not attempted experimenting with 4 or more incorrect attempts in a row.

The workaround is to simply lock and unlock the screen once or twice and then slide to unlock. This method will unlock the phone without a password 100% of the time.

Has anyone seen this before and can it be cured?

Comment: I'd just set a password you remember and backup just in case. I have no idea how this would happen

Comment: If you enable lock screen notifications for f.lux, it should work without asking for a passcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [an issue of f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/forum/topic/1246/ios-randomly-asking-for-passcode-while-using-flux/2), but it seems there's no solution for the problem. And sadly I don't think this issue will be patched soon as [Apple stopped f.lux team developing the app for iOS](https://justgetflux.com/sideload/).

Comment: Thank you, that was definitely the problem. f.lux had other problems so I had to uninstall it and then this problem immediately went away.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a bug.

Make a [backup](https://www.apple.com/sg/support/iphone/backup/) of your iPhone in iTunes. Reboot (shutdown and power up) the phone, then try setting a 4-digit passcode and locking the iPhone. Reboot the phone again and unlock the phone using the 4-digit passcode. Then, go into Settings and remove the passcode.

If this does not work (i.e. the phone prompts you for a passcode after this procedure) you are best off just [backing up](https://www.apple.com/sg/support/iphone/backup/) again and [restoring](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT201252). Otherwise, you should go and see Apple Support and get your phone replaced. Remember to [backup](https://www.apple.com/sg/support/iphone/backup/) first if you are! You may not have warranty anymore, but chances are if you tell them your problem, they'll just replace the phone for you.

By the way, just to answer your last question: I have not (yet, touch wood) but [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212479/i-updated-my-ipod-5-gen-to-ios-9-and-now-it-has-a-6-digit-passcode?rq=1) sounds related. And I don't know if it can be cured, but give it a shot. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a full backup of your device to iTunes.
Then do a full reset of your device (Settings > General > Reset > Erase all content and settings).
Then restore your iPhone from the iTunes backup.